# Replicate value based on values in another column in dataframe R

Tags: r

I have written some code that loops over xlsx files in a folder.  At a certain stage in the loop the data frame looks like the one below. What I want to achieve is that the values of column B are replicated along with the values of column A. So: Replicate column B until the group in column A changes value. If there is no value along with the group in column A, leave it empty. This would result in the second dataframe

```
'A' 'B' 'C'    'D'  'E'
 1  50  'ABCD'  10  20
 1      'JNHF'
 1      'edfw'
 2  100 'b984'
 2      'abcd'
 2      'abcd'
 3      'abcd'  24
 3      'b984'
 4 25   'JNHF'
 4      'JNHF'
 4      'b984'
```

The result would be this:

```
'A' 'B' 'C'    'D' 'E' 
 1  50  'ABCD' 10  20
 1  50  'JNHF' 10  20
 1  50  'edfw' 10  20
 2  100 'b984'
 2  100 'abcd'
 2  100 'abcd'
 3      'abcd' 24
 3      'b984' 24
 4  25  'JNHF'
 4  25  'JNHF'
 4  25  'b984'
```

For this I have written the following code.

```
 names <- c('B','D','E')

 for(j in 1:length(names)){
  for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
    if(df[,names[j]][i] == '' & df[,names[1]][i] == df[,names[1]][i-1] ){
        df[,numbers[j]][i] <- df[,names[j]][i-1] 
     }
    }
 }
```

The code returns:

```
 Error in if (df[, names[j]][i] == "" & df[, names[1]][i] == df[, names[1]][i -  : 
   argument is of length zero
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace blank with `NA` and then use `tidyr::fill`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(names), na_if, "") %>% group_by(A) %>% tidyr::fill(names)

#       A B     C    
#   <int> <chr> <fct>
# 1     1 50    ABCD 
# 2     1 50    JNHF 
# 3     1 50    edfw 
# 4     2 100   b984 
# 5     2 100   abcd 
# 6     2 100   abcd 
# 7     3 NA    abcd 
# 8     3 NA    b984 
# 9     4 25    JNHF 
#10     4 25    JNHF 
#11     4 25    b984
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), B = c("50", "", "", "100", "", "", "", "", "25", "", ""), 
C = structure(c(2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L
), .Label = c("abcd", "ABCD", "b984", "edfw", "JNHF"), 
class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks for your fast comment. I see there is a mismatch in the datatable I created as an example and the code that I actually want to run.I added the 'names' in the loop because there are multiple columns in the dataframe that have to edited. So lets say column, B, D and E. Ill change it in my question too.

Comment: I think replacing `tidyr::fill(B)` with `tidyr::fill(one_of(names))` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works perfectly. Just one additional question.  Now what would happen in case a group has two different values? for example 25 in first row of the group and 50 in the 3rd row of that same group?

Comment: What `fill` does is it replaces missing values with latest non missing values. So if you had this vector `c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3)` it would become `c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (using data provided by @RonakShah - thank you):

```
# Convert factors to character strings: clean_df => data.frame
clean_df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(w){if(is.factor(w)){as.character(w)}else{w}}), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Replace blank stirngs with values filled downwards grouping by A: stdout
data.frame(lapply(clean_df, function(x){
        return(ave(x, clean_df$A, FUN = function(z){
          ifelse(any(!(is.na(z))), na.omit(z)[cumsum(!is.na(z))], NA)
          }
        )
      )
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Timminator with a slight modification of the `names` variable and `for` loop  as shown below:

```
names <- c("'B'","'D'","'E'")
#
for(j in 1:length(names)){
  for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
    if(df[i,names[j]] == '' & df[i,1] == df[i-1,1]){
       df[i,names[j]] <- df[i-1,names[j]] 
    }
  }
}
```

> We can get the following desired output

```
> df
   'A' 'B'    'C' 'D' 'E'
1    1  50 'ABCD'  10  20
2    1  50 'JNHF'  10  20
3    1  50 'edfw'  10  20
4    2 100 'b984'        
5    2 100 'abcd'        
6    2 100 'abcd'        
7    3     'abcd'  24    
8    3     'b984'  24    
9    4  25 'JNHF'        
10   4  25 'JNHF'        
11   4  25 'b984'
```

> Using the following data as input

```
df<- structure(list("'A'" = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L,4L), 
                    "'B'" = c("50", "", "", "100", "", "", "", "", "25", "", ""), 
                    "'C'" = structure(c(2L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L
                    ), .Label = c("'b984'", "'ABCD'", "'JNHF'", "'abcd'", 
                                  "'b984'", "'edfw'", "'JNHF'"), class = "factor"), 
                    "'D'" = c("10", "", "", "", "", "", "24", "", "", "", ""), 
                    "'E'" = c("20","", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA,-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Sachin2014, thank you for your reply. I am curious what the reason is for putting the columnnames in quotes.

Comment: It will work without quotes as well. I used quotes just to create the output exactly as you had described in your question. 'A' vs A.